# amcl tuning for better localization

Tags: localization, navigation, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm pretty desperate right now because I can't figure out where my mistake is. I hope someone can enlighten me.

When I try to localize my robot (while driving) the laserscan data moves with it (but it should stay on the obstacles in the static map I use). In detail: I set the robots pose with the "2D Pose Estimate". I drive towards a wall (using robot steering) and as the robot approaches the wall the laserscan data moves towards the robot. As a result of that the robot does not localize properly. [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/eehqasyp29u0tee/AAAT8VsVWWBrYLN3kbg4rMOJa?dl=0) are two screenshots of rviz for better visualization (before and after driving)
Can anyone give me a hint into the right direction?

Any help would be appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261623/amcl-tuning-for-better-localization/) by [peterwe](https://answers.ros.org/users/28779/peterwe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2017-05-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2017-05-17**:
please, post your amcl config and your tf tree.
is this a real robot or a simulation? how are you generating your odometry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm sorry for the late reply. Thank you for your help but I figured out the problem. It was in the base_controller responsible for handling the cmd_vel commands.

---

Originally posted by [peterwe](https://answers.ros.org/users/28779/peterwe/) with karma: 36 on 2017-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JKRoopan](https://answers.ros.org/users/133396/jkroopan/) on 2023-01-11**:
What was the reason for the error in laserscan data